# What is the best way a menu item to Vista's explorer to start a command prompt in the current directory?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line-interface

What is the best way to add a menu item to Vista's explorer to start a command prompt in the current directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shift-Right click on the folder and click on Open Command Window Here.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work on my Vista install.

Comment: Weird...what version of Vista is it? You are clicking on the folder once, then holding down shift and right-clicking?

Comment: Note that this only works for folders in the right hand pane of explorer. It also works on network shares, in which case it will map a drive letter temporarily for you.

Comment: Works for me (Vista Enterprise)

Comment: That is it. I was right clicking in the left pane's tree. It works when I shift right click the folders int he left pane. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shift+right-click as AdamB pointed out.

If you have UAC enabled and you'd like to have an additional context menu item to open an elevated command (or PowerShell) prompt, see [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.06.utilityspotlight.aspx?pr=blog).